# Автоматическое создание поддомена

Tags: php

Могу ли я сделать так?
Существует некий юзер на сайте, у него есть функция создать компанию.
После нажатия необходимо на сервере создать новый поддомен такого вида: `nameCompany.site.ru`
При переходе по ссылке `nameCompany.site.ru`необходимо отображать frontend, но если такого не существует кидать ошибку?

Comment: можно модифицировать конфиг апача, но, боюсь, его надо перегружать. а можно через htacces отправлять все запросы к поддоменам на скрипт, а там разбираться

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, можете. Настраиваете любой веб-сервер, что бы запросы всех поддоменов шли на один входной `php` скрипт, в котором уже реализуете проверку поддоменов и свой роутинг.

### UPD

Как мне правильно напомнили, забыл написать про обязательную конфигурацию так же `DNS`, что бы запросы на все поддомены в принципе доходили до сервера.

Comment: только надо заранее в ДНС  сделать запись типа : `  *   IN    A    WEB_SERVER_IP `